# UIAutomator2 and Android Studio emulator issues on M1 Mac

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio

I'm having trouble starting the AtxAgent of UIAutomator2:
[image]

Trying to start the atx server from command line:

```
adb shell /data/local/tmp/atx-agent server --nouia --addr :7912
```

Gives:

```
/system/bin/sh: /data/local/tmp/atx-agent: not executable: 32-bit ELF file
```

I'm running this from Android Studio on an M1 Mac mini (Arm).
I'm emulating a Pixel 2 with Android 10 for arm64. I have also tried Android 11, 12 and Sv2 and get the same error.
This works on my Intel Mac mini, so issue might be arm related?

Answer (score 2):

This error was due to the atx-agent not being compiled for arm64 v8.
I downloaded the source and compiled it then pushed to the emulator and now it works.

OSX instructions
Don't remember exactly how I did it, but these are my notes (you first need to install HomeBrew):

```
brew install go

sh build-run-fg.sh

go mod download github.com/BurntSushi/toml
```

Then to install the agent on your device. First get the device using
adb devices

Then:

```
 adb -s emulator-5554 push atx-agent /data/local/tmp/atx-agent
 adb -s emulator-5554 shell chmod 755 /data/local/tmp/atx-agent
 adb -s emulator-5554 shell /data/local/tmp/atx-agent server -d
```

Comment: How though? I'm unfamiliar..

Comment: Updated answer to include instructions